# #c textbox to database - error

Tags: c#, database, syntax, textbox

I'm writing a program that send you the textbox.text to database (table is werknemers)

But I'm getting an error and I think that it is coming from the database but I'm not sure.

Here is a screenshot of my error:

http://gyazo.com/6895862b5c4f60539a245bc11f2d36b9

Here is a screenshot of my table in the database:

http://gyazo.com/d71cf2e1db26791e98aef3e304d2b90d

Sorry that you cannot or don't know the column name but the language is dutch.

I think that there is a problem with the `nvarchar`

Here is my code:

```
private void btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand scmdWerknemergegevens;
    scmdWerknemergegevens = new SqlCommand("insert into werknemers(naam, voornaam, straat, huisnr, postcode, gemeente, burgerlijkestand, geboorte_datum, kinderen_ten_laste, afdeling, in_dienst_sinds, gewest, minder_valide, minder_valide_partner, minder_valide_kinderen, inkomen_partner, [e-mail], tel_nr, gsm_nr) values (@naam, @voornaam, @straat, @huisnr, @postcode, @gemeente, @burgerlijkestand, @geboorte_datum, @kinderen_ten_laste, @afdeling, @in_dienst_sinds, @gewest, @minder_valide, @minder_valide_partner, @minder_valide_kinderen, @inkomen_partner, @[e-mail], @tel_nr, @gsm_nr)",loonberekening);

    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", txtNaam.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", txtVoornaam.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@straat", txtStraat.Text);

    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@huisnr", txtStraatnr.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", txtPostcode.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gemeente", txtGemeente.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@burgerlijkestand", txtStand.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geboorte_datum", txtGeboortedatum.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kinderen_ten_laste", txtKinderentenlaste.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@afdeling", txtAfdeling.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@in_dienst_sinds", txtIndien.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gewest", txtGewest.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minder_valide", cbxValide.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minder_valide_partner", cbxPartner.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minder_valide_kinderen", txtHoeveelvalidekinderen.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inkomen_partner", txtInkomenpartner.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[e-mail]", txtEmail.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_nr", txtTelefoonnr.Text);
    scmdWerknemergegevens.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gsm_nr", txtGsmNr.Text);

    try
    {
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(txtPostcode.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception h)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide number only");
    }

    scmdWerknemergegevens.Connection = loonberekening;

    loonberekening.Open();
    scmdWerknemergegevens.ExecuteNonQuery();
    loonberekening.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error and add a tag for the database your using.

Comment: `@[e-mail]` looks odd, try a more reasonable `@email`

Comment: Hi thanks for helping but now i am getting this error: http://gyazo.com/4d9a0a3a06186e3b0b89d0bef90290ce

Comment: You should specify datatypes of `SqlCommand` parameters and do some datatypes conversion from text

Comment: Did you change *both* `@[e-mail]`?

Comment: yes i did changed both

Comment: You have three "e-mail" there, make sure you change all three of them. Search your code for hyphen "-" since this is where the syntax breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scmdWerknemergegevens = new SqlCommand(@"insert into werknemers(naam, voornaam, straat, huisnr, postcode, gemeente, burgerlijkestand, geboorte_datum, kinderen_ten_laste, afdeling, in_dienst_sinds, gewest, minder_valide, minder_valide_partner, minder_valide_kinderen, inkomen_partner, [e-mail], tel_nr, gsm_nr) values (@naam, @voornaam, @straat, @huisnr, @postcode, @gemeente, @burgerlijkestand, @geboorte_datum, @kinderen_ten_laste, @afdeling, @in_dienst_sinds, @gewest, @minder_valide, @minder_valide_partner, @minder_valide_kinderen, @inkomen_partner, @[e-mail], @tel_nr, @gsm_nr)",loonberekening);
```